# SP2013 - How many values can be stored in multivalue lookup columns?

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, limitations, boundaries

as I am currently designing a tool for one of our customers, we want to use multivalued lookup columns.
As there is no real limititation set for the amount of source data we fear it could reach for a boundary of SharePoint.

I've also searched the widewidewide internet to no avail, so I hope anyone is able to give me a hint on that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "it depends". Eventually you'll run into the [2100 parameter SQL Server limit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/specify-parameters). You'll have to simply test your particular list as each column (for which many are hidden) also count against this parameter limit.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This limit I have seen, but didn't connected it to this question.
Which columns do you mean? The ones of the source? So if the source did not have that many columns we could optimize it a bit?